# Update Google Sheet from Email Attachment Using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I receive bank statements from the same Email Id and the Same Subject containing an attachment of spreadSheet after every 1 hour on my Gmail.

I want to create a "Google App Script" to update my master google spreadsheet automatically from this email attachment.

As per my understanding, it should be as below steps;

1. find the last email from the specified subject and email ID,
2. save the attachment to the specified Google Drive Folder.
3. From the master sheet pick the last spreadsheet from the above-specified folder.
4. Update data in the master sheet.

Is it possible? if yes how?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Yes it is possible. But there are many ways to do it, so please share the code you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck, and we will try to help you the best we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. get the email with [search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max)
2. get the attachment with [getAttachments()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getattachments) and save with [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)
3. get sheets with [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
4. update sheet with [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) or [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)